# blogger to pelican nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I just converted my blog from blogger to pelican. On blogger, posts used to be something like: http://blog.example.com/2014/09/title-slug.html, now my blog on pelican is http(s)://blog.exmaple.com/title-slug.html.

Now that I've moved from blogger to pelican (self-hosting), I want to rewrite URL types from blogger to the one I'm using on pelican.

I've never actually done regexp or nginx rewrite rules, so I'm lost as to how I should go about writing those rules. I've tried a few looking at some examples, but they aren't working. E.g:

```
location ^/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/\.html$ {
    rewrite ^(.*) /$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it out of the location block, then this should work:

```
rewrite ^/\d+/\d+/([^/]+\.html)$ /$1 permanent;
```

Comment: You forgot the multiplicity operator in the capture group pattern.

Comment: @XavierLucas Ahh good point, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the regex operator : `~`.

```
location ~ ^/\d+/\d+/([-\w]+)\.html$ {
    return 301 /$1.html;
}
```